# ¿Cómo hacer join entre tablas sin duplicar registros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo dos tablas (se muestran en la siguiente imagen) cuando hago un `left join` entre las tablas por medio de la columna **IdPoliza** obtengo un resultado con 4 registros.

Lo que yo deseo es solo obtener dos registros ya sea como la opción 1 u opción 2 en el cual tanto la columna **IdAbonoProveedor** e **IdPolizaDetalle** sean únicas en sus columnas correspondientes, estoy usando SQLServer 2012

`SELECT * 
FROM Tabla1 t1
LEFT JOIN Tabla2 t2 ON t1.IdPoliza = t2.idPoliza`

[image: Descripción del problema]

Espero me puedan apoyar y me haya podido dar a entender, gracias

Comment: Deberías poner la consulta que estás realizando ahora

Comment: Has intentado usar DISTINCT ? o Group By ?

Comment: La forma de resolver esto es que exista un `id` que relacione univocamente las filas de ambas tablas, por ejemplo si en tabla2 tuvieras un IdAbonoProveedor. Podría proponerte generar un "número de renglón" para cada tabla y relacionar estos, pero ¿que ocurre si una tabla tiene más filas que la otra?.

Answer (score 0):

Con esto obtienes los distintos IdAbonoProveedor, IdPolizaDetalle  que cumplen el join

select distinct IdAbonoProveedor, IdPolizaDetalle 
from Tabla1 a left join tabla2 b on b.IdPoliza = a.idPoliza

También se podría contar la cantidad de veces que ocurren estos campos de esta forma:

select idAbonoProveedor, IdPolizaDetalle, count(*)
from Tabla1 a left join tabla2 b on b.IdPoliza = a.idPoliza
group by idAbonoProveedor, IdPolizaDetalle

Espero te sirva!!